# Can Perfmon be configured to survive a hard-reset or flush reports on the go?

Tags: windows, log-files, windows-server-2016, performance-monitoring, perfmon

I am having trouble configuring `perfmon` here (Windows Server 2016 if it's relevant). My situation: our server recently get random hit and we are diagnosing the problem, so I put a Data Collector Set. What we want: Memory usage data every 30 seconds.

I realize that without Stop Condition, the report won't be written at all. It is only updated to the file when it stop. So I put the `Restart the data collector set at limits` and set the `Duration` to 1 minutes. However, this cause the Report to be in a file for every minute, which is undesirable.

If we don't set it, we don't get the updated file and we doubt it is saved if we perform a hard-reset (from AWS) if a problem happens.

Is there a way/free alternative that we can get a report written live?

Answer (score 1):

You could use SNMP trap to get information of the server, it is completely free.
It could be added in the add features wizard (SNMP Service).

Once you add it go to services.msc find the SNMP service and configure it (if you want can change the user run it), under the tab security create the SNMP community a readonly one will really sufficient, googling for more details on how to configure snmp on windows; (here the official doc: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/snmp/snmp-start-page)

Now you get your SNMP service up and running, you have just to choose how to collect data, there are many tools could you help with this, my personal suggestion is to use cacti (https://www.cacti.net/) but if you do not have the possibility to run another server you can script and run in scheduled task the snmpwalk to get and save data as you want (http://www.net-snmp.org/)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Sorry still feel a bit complicated to me. We will make an in-house solution for this one, simpler for us developers :)

Comment: There have also some solution ready and easy to setup like opsview, solarwinds, but that are not properly free ;); I think about also you can get some powershell script ready out of the box or can inspire you to get your goal, like this: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-Script-to-Get-78687c5e

Comment: Thanks but C# was much simpler to us. We have already created the utility and shared it on Github too ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I wrote a simple in-house solution here, this repository includes a build and the source code in C# if anyone want some minor change:

https://github.com/datvm/LukeVo.MemoryMonitor